# Mathematica code in LaTeX document

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, rendering

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*\variable[1]{\textcolor{teal}{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \texttt{Table[A/(A - r*X) - (1 + r)\^{}\variable{k}, \{\variable{k}, 1, 10\}]}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If I copy the code and paste it into Mathematica, the rendering of the `^` is wrong; see the following picture:

[image: Mathematica]

How do I get an output which I can paste (directly) into Mathematica without having to change `^` manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `\string^` seems to work as expected:

[image]